# Hyphenated classname in link_to breaks remote: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have the following `link_to`

`<%= link_to "some page", some_page_path(id: page.id), class: 'js-cssClassName', remote: true %>`

When clicked it gives a HTML response instead of the desired js response.  If I change the class to 'cssClassName' i.e. no "js-" it works as expected.  Likewise if I wrap the class parameter in html it works too.

`<%= link_to "some page", some_page_path(id: page.id), html: {class: 'js-cssClassName'}, remote: true %>`

I have never seen this issue before, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`<%= link_to "some page", some_page_path(id: page.id), html: {class: 'js-cssClassName'}, remote: true %>` *worked* because is doesn't apply the class ;)

The real issue was that I had a listener on the class with `evt.stopPropagation();` which blocked the js response.